# How to serve images in nodejs express

Tags: node.js, express

I have this code

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');

var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/uploads'));

console.log("listen to 8080");
server.listen(8080);
```

I have my image in `/uploads/test.jpg` but when I go to `http://localhost:8080/uploads/test.jpg` I get `Cannot GET /uploads/test.jpg`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The `static` method indicates which *root* folder you will be serving your static content from. At the moment, your image will be accessible from http://localhost:8080/test.jpg.

To serve the images from a sub-folder, you would need to create this folder inside the `static` directory e.g.

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

- public
-- uploads
---- test.jpg
```

Answer (score 6):

app.use function has a default of '/' . When a route other than '/' is given , the middle-ware handle is useful only when the path segment is in the requests  path name. For example if we mount a function in '/example' it would be invoked on  /example and not at '/'. So your request is at "/uploads/test.jpg"
To do this

```
app.use('/uploads', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Now the middle ware is mounted at '/uploads' and services and any request made with path '/uploads' like **GET /uploads/test.jpg etc.**

Answer (score 3):

Use the following code to serve images, CSS files, and JavaScript files in a directory named public.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

Now, you can load the files that are in the public directory:

Examples:

```
localhost:3000/images/kitten.jpg
localhost:3000/css/style.css
localhost:3000/js/app.js
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
app.use('/static', express.static('./public'));

app.listen(2020, () => {
  console.log("Server Started");
})
```

Run:
localhost:2020/static/test.jpg

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.